# Can't Connect PHP - Oracle 11g

Tags: php, oracle, xampp, oci8

Just Trying to connect PHP to remoted Oracle 11g
and still not good to go.

This is my phpinfo

[image: PHPINFO]

```
<?php
 $dbx = "(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = 192.168.1.131)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = TESDB)))";

$dbz = "//192.168.1.131:1521/TESDB";


$db = oci_connect("user1", "user123", $dbz);

if (!$db) die("Error connecting to Oracle database: " . oci_error());

echo "Successfully connected to Oracle database!";

?>
```

I have 2 variables $dbx and $dbz
tried both of them, both are failed
even oci_error doesn't give me a message error
am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: `Oracle Run-time Client Library Version` showing `0.0.0.0` is odd. Mine shows the exact client version, `11.2.0.3.0`. Do you have `error_reporting` and `display_errors` set appropriately?

Comment: `oci_error()` returns an array so you won't see the error. Assuming you are using at least PHP 5.4 you can simply change the code to `oci_error()['message']`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the line:

```
$dbz = "//192.168.1.131:1521/TESDB"
```

The `;` is missing, try this:

```
<?php
$dbz = "192.168.1.131:1521/TESDB";
$conn = oci_connect("user1", "user123", $dbz);
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    echo "Successfully connected to Oracle database!";
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry my bad..typo
but not because of that :D

Comment: No Error..just printed "Error connecting to Oracle database"..even oci_error doen't give error at all (Using my code)...using your code, no error message at all